# Check if an application emits sound

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, cscore

today I am here to ask you how you can "*understand*" if a given application is emitting sound. 
On windows 7 and 8 I use the following code (library [**CSCore Audio**](https://cscore.codeplex.com/) )

```
[...]
        AudioSessionManager2 sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render);
        AudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator();

                AudioSessionControl2 sessionControl;
                foreach (AudioSessionControl session in sessionEnumerator)
                {
                    sessionControl = session.QueryInterface<AudioSessionControl2>();
                    if (sessionControl.Process.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith("my_test"))
                    {
                        sessione = sessionControl;
                        audio = session.QueryInterface<AudioMeterInformation>();
                        break;
                    }
                }

        control.Text = sessione.Process.MainWindowTitle + "[" + audio.PeakValue + "]";
    [...]
```

It works well, but not on Windows XP. 
Is there a way "*universal*" to do it? 
If there would be a way to do this in Java would be even better, so work on Linux (which for the moment I do not need, but maybe in the future)

Comment: sorry, I forgot .... It's not even the first time I write here :( Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but Windows XP does not querying the audio peak of a process. You can also take a look at the [Windows XP Audio Mixer](http://technodigits.files.wordpress.com/2007/06/soundmixerxp.jpg). There is no peak displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. 
Do you know if you can do it on Linux via Java?
Or at least something to tell if a given process is emitting sound ...

Comment: I am sorry. I've got no idea whether it is possible on Linux.